# Only Error icon is visible while setting error to EditText in InputTextLayout

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-textinputlayout

When user enter invalid `email` or `mobile` while registration, I am setting error to `EditText`.

Please check below code:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/txt_input_mobile_number"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input_mobile_number"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Mobile number"
            android:maxLength="10"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:maxLines="1"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

`MyFragment.java` implements below `OnKeyListener`:

```
 @Override
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
            // perform validation of data here
            switch (v.getId()) {

                case R.id.input_mobile_number:
                    EditText editMobile = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.input_mobile_number);
                    Editable phone = binding.inputMobileNumber.getText();
                    if (phone != null && isValidMobile(phone.toString())) {
                        editMobile.setError("Please enter valid mobile number");
                        editMobile.requestFocus();
                    }
                    break;
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Below screenshot displays, Only error icon is visible not error box like other one:

**with only symbol**
[image]

**with error prompt**

[image]

Comment: It is hard to get which version is desired and what you wana achive.  so we have: *When user enter invalid email or mobile while registration, I am setting error to EditText.
Below screenshot displays, Only error icon is visible not error box like other one* ... and some code dump **without showing what is the problem**

Comment: Try to set error to `InputTextLayout` you are setting to `EditText` that's why..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `TextInputLayout` instead of `EditText` for your **Requirement** .

```
TextInputLayout tilObj = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.txt_input_mobile_number);
tilObj .setErrorEnabled(true);
tilObj .setError("Please enter valid mobile number");
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured out!!

When we use `TextInputLayout` we need to **set error not to `EditText` but `TextInputLayout` itself**.

So I have changed my code as below:

```
  @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if ((event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) &&
                    (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                // perform validation of data here
                switch (v.getId()) {

                    case R.id.input_mobile_number:
                      // check it is TextInputLayout not EditText
                        TextInputLayout editMobile = (EditText)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txt_input_mobile_number);
                        Editable phone = binding.inputMobileNumber.getText();
                        if (phone != null && isValidMobile(phone.toString())) {
                            editMobile.setError("Please enter valid mobile number");
                            editMobile.requestFocus();
                        }
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the space between these two TextInputLayout is low and you cannot see the error message , try to put more margin between them.